# C++ Find and remove references to little-used library

Tags: gcc, gnu, ld

I'm modifying a large collection of legacy C++ code which has a few dependencies on the old commoncpp library.  We want to replace commoncpp with something more modern (e.g. Boost).

First I need to find all the places commoncpp-provided functions and methods are used.  The obvious brute force methods take too much time (especially for "lazy" programmers like me who believe computers should do the tedious work :-).

I'm looking for ideas on how to speed up the process.

If `ld` had a flag that said "continue looking for external references and spit out any missing references" that might do the everything needed.

Our code is spread over many directories, with hierarchal, recursive Makefiles, if that makes a difference to a proposed solution.

Environment is FreeBSD with Gnu compiler chain.

I tagged this with C as well, since most solutions which would solve this kind of problem for C should solve it for C++ also.

(guess you can't format comments)

Using `--cxref` in my build, and then this pipeline:

```
% egrep 'ccgnu2|ccext2' output.txt | sort | uniq
```

Gets me this:

```
on-virtual thunk to ost::ttystream::~ttystream() ../../lib/libccext2.so
non-virtual thunk to ost::unixstream::~unixstream() ../../lib/libccext2.so
ost::CRC16Digest::getSize() ../../lib/libccext2.so
ost::CRC16Digest::initDigest() ../../lib/libccext2.so
ost::CRC16Digest::~CRC16Digest() ../../lib/libccext2.so
ost::CRC32Digest::getSize() ../../lib/libccext2.so
```

I wonder if I can so something useful with the above to get what I need.

Comment: how about compiling the code without actually having the library on the machine? Is it not possible?

Comment: well, from my personal experience, we saw all old library were in separate dir, and we stopped that dir from getting included in build. So in 1st step, we got files not found error in build log. Simply removed that ( you can get the missing file names in build log and recursively delete those thru `sed+find`). Then another build gave linker error for those functions, and followed the same procedure (only removing functions were manual, because new functions had to be included there)

Comment: 0A0D: No, the libraries are added to the gcc link library list for all C++ programs via a standard included Makefile.

Elazar: I am doing that now.  Compile stops with fatal after finding first missing external.  There are many files and many programs, so this method is very slow and tedious.

abasu: See above.  I'm very adept with Unix command line filters and scripting, but the problem is finding all symbols in one compile.  Removing libraries (2 of them, libccgnu2 and libccext2) causes fatal stop on first error.

Comment: Standard BSD Makefiles.

Comment: Well, can you add -gstabs flag and grep the stabs for the (possibly mangled) names? I guess if the library is in a different namespace this could work.

Comment: And you may find the `--cref` flag useful: "Output a cross reference table... The format of the table is intentionally simple, so that it may be easily processed by a script if necessary."

Comment: --cref looks like a good possibility!

Comment: @CXJ - sorry. it looks like it is not - it only prints the library defining the symbols (at least in the code I checked it with).

Comment: Am trying some things out.  Will report back shortly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the `ld` man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ld) :

> --warn-unresolved-symbols
>
> > If the linker  is going  to report an unresolved symbol (see the option --unresolved-symbols) it will
> >     normally  generate an error. This option makes it generate a warning
> >     instead.

All you need to do is compile without linking the actual library.

On my machine:

```
~/workspace/jos$ make 2>&1 | grep reference
lib/spawn.c:129: warning: undefined reference to `copy_shared_pages'
user/primes.c:25: warning: undefined reference to `fork'
.
.
.
```

Comment: Hm, that might work.  It certainly gets me as close as my --cxref filtering.  Will try some variations on it and see what I can do.

Comment: @CXJ What is missing here? you even have line numbers.

Comment: I get more verbose output, but with some shell scripting, I think I can mash it into something I can use. :-)   Thanks much!